# What is qx.event.type.Event.addPromise() used for?

Tags: qooxdoo

I was looking through the apiviewer  and I noticed there is a method [addPromise(promise)](http://www.qooxdoo.org/qxl.apiviewer/#qx.event.type.Event~addPromise!method_public) in the class qx.event.type.Event. I searched through the qooxdoo organization in Github for use cases but I couldn't find any. Can someone provide an example of use for that method?

Answer (score 3):

It's because collecting promises typically relies on a function returning the promise, but the event firing API is baked in with the return value being a boolean (see `fireEvent` and `fireDataEvent` in [MEvent.js](https://www.qooxdoo.org/current/api/#qx.core.MEvent).

In other circumstances, we've added a new function with the `Async` suffix (eg property called "myProperty" can have `setMyPropertyAsync`) which allows us to separate a promise based path through the code from the old non-promise, synchronous code - so we're able to introduce new features while maintaining strict backwards compatibility (features which would otherwise require a breaking API change)

But that's not possible with events, because `fireEvent`/`fireDataEvent` are so ubiquitous and fundamentally synchronous, so they *must* continue to return a boolean.

We're trading on the fact that events are typically used in an asynchronous way, and the fact that the boolean return value of `fireEvent` is only used to determine whether the event was `preventDefault()`-ed or not.  This makes it a requirement that events cannot be `preventDefaulted()` asynchronously (well, they probably can in reality but there could conceivably be a situation where it is not 100% reliable to do so).

However, because the return value is not a promise and cannot be chained, we have to provide a mechanism to chain it - the `addPromise` method allows callers to add promises to the chain, and then the framework will grab those promises later by calling `event.promise()` - see [qx.event.Registration.fireNonBubblingEventAsync](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/event/Registration.js#L434-L459).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately I still can't wrap my head around this promise based event mechanism. Is there any example usage, in the framework or elsewhere?